# How to get data from contract in brownie python script?

Tags: solidity, brownie

Say I have a `contract` `Box` that has a `public` state variable:

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public addressToAddressToUint;
```

now in my python brownie script I would like to read a value from this variable in a given deployed `Box` contract like so:

```py
lastBox = Box[-1]

address0 = '0x123...'
address1 = '0x321...'

# not sure show to access a mapping in brownie, but the following doesn't work
uintValue = lastBox.addressToAddressToUint[address0][address1]
```

How exactly would I go about indexing such a mapping in brownie?

Comment: Try: uintValue = lastBox.addressToAddressToUint(address0, address1)